# PHP Doc comment after unserialization

Tags: php, reflection

The `ReflectionMethod` instance from PHP (http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionmethod.php) has the `getDocComment` method that returns the annotation of a method. This works ok, unless you use unserialized object.

```
$ref = new ReflectionClass('a');
var_dump(method_exists($ref, 'getDocComment')); //bool(true)
var_dump($ref->getDocComment()); //bool(false)

$ref = unserialize(serialize($ref));
var_dump(method_exists($ref, 'getDocComment')); //bool(true)
var_dump($ref->getDocComment()); //PHP Warning:  Uncaught Error: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the reflection object
```

Is there any way of testing if the `ReflectionMethod` object has correctly defined doc comment? I mean, I do not care about getting the annotation after serialize/unserialize, but I want to check if calling `getDocComment` is safe.

---

Edit: According to responses that advice error handling + fallback, I rephrase the Q.

I have some simple cache of reflections (array of `ReflectionMethod` objects). Until I use item from that cache, I wold like to chech its correctness. I do NOT want to handle error, I want to "predict error". Awesome would be something like `hasDocComment` method that does not generate any error, but returns only true/false within any `ReflectionMethod` object state.

Comment: Wont getDocComment return false it it does not exist?

Comment: @Erik yes it will - see first part of code

Answer (score 2):

The general approach of serializing reflection objects is wrong. There exists a PHP Bug report for it, but it has been set to "irrelevant":

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70719

The reason is, that you cannot connect a reflection object back to its class again, because you would have to deal with source code changes and all kinds of stuff. What you should do instead is, to serialize the name of the class and generate a NEW reflection object from that class, when you unserialize.

Code Example:

```
class A { }
$ref = new ReflectionClass('A');
var_dump(method_exists($ref, 'getDocComment')); 

// serialize only the class name    
$refClass = unserialize(serialize($ref->getName()));

// get a new reflection object from that class ...
$ref = new ReflectionClass($refClass);
var_dump(method_exists($ref, 'getDocComment')); 

// If you want to serialize an object 
$a = new A();
$a2 = unserialize(serialize($a));
$ref = new ReflectionClass(get_class($a2));
var_dump(method_exists($ref, 'getDocComment'));
```

Comment: I assumed that (+1 for pointing it out), but this is not an answer to my Q. I would like to know how to check if the noted method will fail. Or, modified according to your note, if there is a correct connection between the object and it's class. Can I somehow get that info?

Comment: Serializing only name won't help me since I do serialize object with some data, and that is used as a source object for the reflection... It's part of some dynamic process... I don't need any bypass, I need to check the reference between object and its reflection

Comment: Well in this case you serialize the **object**, not the reflection and then you use get_class(...) to get the class name and a new reflection object from it. In any case you shall never serialize the reflection object itself! The reflection object and the object containing your data is two different kind of shoes.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to handle errors, you can try/catch the execution block. Since [alt-php71-7.1.0-1](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/internal_constructor_behaviour) (which you seem to be using), this will throw an instance of `Error` instead of simply a `Fatal Error`, which allows you to do error handling.

```
<?php
class A { }
$ref = new ReflectionClass('A');
var_dump(method_exists($ref, 'getDocComment')); //bool(true)
var_dump($ref->getDocComment()); //bool(false)

// serialize only the class name    
$refClass = unserialize(serialize($ref));
try {
    $refClass->getDocComment();
    // do your work
}
catch (Error $e) {
    echo "Malformed Reflection object: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/SliR1)

And since you can still get the class name from the malformed `Reflection` instance, you can instantiate a new one right in your `catch` block:

```
<?php
class A { }
$ref = new ReflectionClass('A');
var_dump(method_exists($ref, 'getDocComment')); //bool(true)
var_dump($ref->getDocComment()); //bool(false)

// serialize only the class name    
$refClass = unserialize(serialize($ref));
try {
    $refClass->getDocComment();
}
catch (Error $e) {
    $recoveredRef = new ReflectionClass($refClass->getName());
    var_dump($recoveredRef);
    var_dump($recoveredRef->getDocComment()); // works correctly
    echo "Malformed Reflection object, but recovered: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/cFpdR)

Comment: Nice answer, but still not answering my question... see the edit above